# Are there any repercussions to storing globals like this?

Tags: javascript, window, global

So I know polluting the global namespace referencing the window is a bad thing, especially if you have multiple 3rd party references. So this would be not desirable:

```
window.someObject = someObject;
```

That will reference it everywhere. What if I instead use it like this?

```
var MyApplication = window.MyApplication;
MyApplication.someObject = someObject;
```

Of course using this approach requires referencing `MyApplication = window.MyApplication` at the top of each module that needs access to this created namespace. So back to my question. Is this an acceptable approach to giving global access without polluting the window global namespace?

Comment: If you want global access, you need to have a global of some sort.  This is the common way of doing it.

Comment: I'm going to assume since you said it's common way of doing it that means it's completely acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want global access, you need to have a global of some sort. This is the common way of doing it.

An example from the [jQuery source code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js):

```
_jQuery = window.jQuery,
_$ = window.$,
```

I believe all of the big frameworks do it this way.  I'd consider it perfectly acceptable to pollute the global namespace with one container variable.

Comment: Thanks for the jQuery reference. If it's common place among other large frameworks, then it's what I'm looking for. I just wanted to check with the community first, because it's something I deduced on my own (which can be dangerous haha).

Comment: I debated the same thing myself a few weeks ago when I started organizing a project.  I'm sure it's a common question.

Comment: Surprisingly I didn't find too much about it on the web. Most articles just talked about adding variables or functions directly into the window namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do (in global context):

```
(function(lib) {

  // in here, lib references window.MyApplication
  ...

}(MyApplication));
```

So you can easily change the object passed in.